# Editing embedded objects in powerpoint

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I have a powerpoint presentation with an excel workbook embedded in one of the slides. I also have a userform that I want the user to input information into, I want to take this information and then edit the excel sheet with the relevant information.

I don't know how to access the excel sheet within powerpoint though so I can change the values of the cells.

Answer (score 3):

```
Sub a()

Dim oSl As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim oSh As PowerPoint.Shape

Set oSl = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)

Set oSh = oSl.Shapes(1)

With oSh.OLEFormat.Object.Sheets(1)
    .Range("A1").Value = .Range("A1").Value + 1
    .Range("A2").Value = .Range("A2").Value - 1
End With

Set oSl = Nothing
Set oSh = Nothing

End Sub
```

Inspired in [this code](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/29897954/embedded-excel-vba-in-powerpoint.aspx)

Comment: I've looked at several solutions for ppt embedded in Excel and have not been successful in being able to make anything work. 

Not helpful.

Comment: @Mike Ok.  I'll try to put the thing together and edit the answer.